# Unable to skip ssl verification with gradle command but able to do so in maven

Tags: maven, ssl, gradle, gradlew

I am currently using gradle publish command but unable to do so, due to `PKIX path building failed unable to find valid certification path to requested target`
when I tried with mvn deploy command
`mvn deploy -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true --debug`
It worked fine.
I want to achieve same with gradle.

Comment: I would ask why do you like to ignore the TLS checking ?

Comment: Coz the URL I am working with is the internal one, and the agent which it is sending request to is also inside the network.

Comment: Does that really matter... if you have TLS connection why is the certificate not correct? It needs to be fixed.

Comment: I have no access over the certificate or the agent, trying to configure it through pipelines. That's why I needed to go through skipping the SSL in my case.

Answer (score 6):

Create the `gradle.properties` file:

```
systemProp.http.ssl.insecure=true
systemProp.http.ssl.allowall=true
systemProp.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true
```